SASS, Gulp watch PHP Files in base directory and subdirectories
I am developing a WordPress theme using SASS and gulp locally. I am new to both SASS and gulp and followed a very good course on creating your own framework. I've got running perfectly on html files however because I am developing a WordPress theme I need it to watch PHP files in the base directory (theme folder) and subdirectories.
My gulpfile.js:
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require("gulp");
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
const purgecss = require("gulp-purgecss");

function buildKraftdeckStyles() {
  return src("kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(purgecss({ content: ["**/**/*.php"] }))
    .pipe(dest("css"));
}

function watchKraftdeck() {
  watch(["kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss, '**/**/*.php"], buildKraftdeckStyles);
}

exports.default = series(buildKraftdeckStyles, watchKraftdeck);

This doesn't seem to work. I've tried .//*.php and !/**/*.php. Where am I going wrong?

I figured it out.. there was error in my code, missing "" so my code is now:
function buildKraftdeckStyles() {
  return src("kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(purgecss({ content: ["**/*.php"] }))
    .pipe(dest("css"));
}

function watchKraftdeck() {
  watch(["kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss", "**/*.php"], buildKraftdeckStyles);
}

You'll see the this line has been corrected from:
  watch(["kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss, '**/**/*.php"], buildKraftdeckStyles);

to:
watch(["kraftdeck-framework/**/*.scss", "**/*.php"], buildKraftdeckStyles);

First I removed the **/ from the beginning and correct the "" and now it works.
